# Converting CComBSTR to _bstr_t with fcopy as false

Tags: com

I believe the following causes a memory access violation error as the false parameter (fcopy) causes the memory to be released for the CComBSTR:

```
CComBSTR myCComBSTR;
string strMyCComBSTR = string(_bstr_t(myCComBSTR, false));
```

However, I'm not quite sure why this is as the MSDN documentation says the following about fcopy:

> If false, the bstr argument is
>   attached to the new object without
>   making a copy by calling
>   SysAllocString.

My question is:

1. Am I right in saying that this is a problem
2. If so - why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a problem - both `myCComBSTR` and the temporary will try to free the string since they both will think they own it.

You see, `fcopy` having value of `false` means "please don't duplicate the string body, just attach to the body I give you". When the  first line completes you have `myCComBSTR` owning the string buffer and when the temporary object on the second line is created it also takes ownership of the same string buffer because of `fcopy` being `false`. Then the temporary is destroyed and frees the string buffer. Later `myCComBSTR` will be destroyed and will try to free the same string buffer again - you run into so-called *double free* which induces undefined behavior.

Comment: +1 Would this also be a problem if we used a BSTR instead of a CComBSTR? I assume not as BSTR is a raw ptr so would not release memory if it goes out of scope?

Comment: @David Relihan: Do you mean just cast to BSTR like this `(BSTR)something`? That would depend. In your case it would be simpler to just not change `fcopy` and let it be true.

Comment: @David You could also do: `string strMyCComBSTR = string(_bstr_t(myCComBSTR.Detach(), false));` if you don't intend to use `myCComBSTR` later